# hp envy x360 2018 - don't install ubuntu 22

Tags: system-installation, ssd, hp, usb-drive

i have a laptop hp envy x360 from 2018 with SSD 500 GB, I try to install ubuntu 22 from USB flash memory it gives me blink prompt and don't start the installation. please help

as a guide my laptop preferences:
Core i7 , ram 16 GB , Graphics: HD Graphics , Hard disk SSD 500GB, touch screen 15 FHD

Comment: You are trying to install Ubuntu Core 22? That is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number. If this is not correct please EDIT the question. More details are required. Does the install start at all? Did you verify the ISO before making the USB? What program did you use to make the bootable USB? See this site https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)